# What do we call a person who studied humanities, e.g. at university or college?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

What do we call a person who has a background in the humanities as a field of study, e.g. linguistics, comparative literature, but isn't necessarily a humanities academic? Is that correct to say *a humanitarian*?

Comment: To clarify, why do you think there is a word for someone who studied something but is not an expert in it? That would describe nearly everyone in the world in nearly every field of study. Moreover, why would such a word exist only for the humanities? Is there an equivalent word in the social sciences, pure sciences, engineering, or other fields?

Comment: @choster: I suspect that the point of the question is that terms like social scientist(\*), psychologist, historian, scientist, physicist, chemist, engineer, mathematician, statistician, etc., are obvious and well known (\* except for "social scientist", which is not used), but it's not obvious what word would describe a person who has a background in humanities (field of study) (although a student of linguistics is, of course, a linguist).

Comment: @ choster:  
I mean she/he might be an expert in this area, but shouldn't necessesarily be a researcher. Let's say, I need 4 people to have my team: an actor, an artist, an IT specialist and ... - the last one should be a woman or a man that had studied or has been studying humanities (doesn't matter what area exactly). I don't know how here, in the U.S. is correct?

Comment: @ Scott: Thanks, that's exactly what I meant. Probably "a liberal arts expert" or " a liberal arts specialist". What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

No. A humanitarian is someone who helps others in a practical sense (feeds the poor, cures the sick etc.).

I’d just say a liberal arts graduate.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single term nowadays that unambiguously refers to a student of the humanities. Academics will usually identify according to their field: a *[Germanist](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/germanist)* or a *[Byzantinist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Byzantinist)*, a *[rhetorician](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/rhetorician)* or a *[logician](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/logician)*.

The OED gives as the first meaning of *humanist*, from 1589, as follows:

> a. A person who pursues or is expert in the study of the humanities, *esp.* a classical scholar. Also (*Sc.*): *spec.* a Latinist, a professor or teacher of Latin (now *rare*).
>
> b.  Freq. with capital initial. Any of the scholars or educators of the early modern period whose work depended on attentiveness to classical Latin (and, later in the period, Greek), as expressed in, e.g., the rediscovery, editing, or discussion of ancient texts, the imitation of their style in original compositions, and the dissemination of some or all of the wide range of cultural ideals which they were supposed to transmit. Cf. humanism n. 3b.

These meanings have been superseded, however. Out of context, a *humanist* will be understood as someone who subscribes to *humanism*, a term which itself may generally refer to secular humanism.

Older texts may refer to a person learned in the classical liberal arts as a *scholar*, hence the OED

> One who has acquired learning in the ‘Schools’; a learned or erudite person; esp. one who is learned in the classical (i.e. Greek and Latin) languages and their literature.

But this term is even less likely to be interpreted as such than *humanist*, as it generally refers to any academician within their field, especially if the field is not a branch of science or engineering.

The word *humanitarian* has never referred to a student of the humanities, and nowadays is most widely understood as someone who is primarily concerned about human welfare, particularly in responding to a situation or event that involves widespread suffering.

Comment: academician is academic?